# Make chrome to read properly my own file extension

Tags: html, google-chrome, file-extension

I am using on my computer a file extension I invented `.gameos`, in the files with this extension I put html code (html+js+css).

Whenever I try to open this files with Chrome it shows me the plain text of the html document with all of its tags, all the functions of javascript and all style properties of css.

I was wondering if there is a way to solve this problem on my single computer (sort of telling chrome how to read this files) and if there was a way to solve the problem with every computer, so each one will always show the html game and not the plain text.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your browser will by default presume any file ending in *.html or *.htm as a web page. For anything else, it is best if your "server" sets the content type as `text/html`. If you can "serve" your page up from a server, you should be able to control this, but if you are just loading from `file:///` I don't think this will work.